# crystal reports: failed to open connection: code 17

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

The main problem is that my reports work perfectly on my local computer, but when I try to run those reports on client server architecture the following error comes up and application stop working.

I just would like to know how I can fix this error or how I should change the connection string so that it will automatically connect with database and fill the report with data.

I use the following code for getting data form table:
----->

```
Sub printreceipt()
    Try
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim report As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        sql = "SELECT BillNo,ItemName,ItemRate,ItemQty,Amount,GstAmount,TotalAmount,Dic,Discount,RoundOff,Svalue,Zvalue,RoundTotal,Given,Balance,Service FROM SalesItem where BillNo= " & Val(Me.txt_billno.Text) & " and EntryDate= '" & Format(Me.Str_Date.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "' "
        '  Dim rep As SalesBill1 = New SalesBill1()
        Dim rep As CrystalReport4 = New CrystalReport4()
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "SalesItem")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = ds.Tables("SalesItem")
        rep.SetDataSource(dt)
        Dim settings = New PrinterSettings()
        Dim a As String = settings.PrinterName
        Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep
        rep.PrintOptions.PrinterName = a
        rep.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
        rep.Close()
        rep.Dispose()
        Form1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Error**

> failed to open the connection.
>
> temp_2353434p-45325-74453-657453{}.rpt
>
> details. [database vendor code : 17 ]

Any help Appreciated.

Comment: Did you set connection information of your report to point to server?

Comment: also make sure you install Crystal Report runtime on whatever server your are deploying to.